# Practical probabilistic proof systems not based on polynomials

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

All practical probabilistic proof/argument systems I know of are based upon polynomial identity testing in finite fields. These constructions include [QAPs](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/215.pdf), [STARKs](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/046.pdf), [GKR](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/2008-DelegatingComputation.pdf) and many variants. In particular, they all rely on the [Schwartz-Zippel lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz%E2%80%93Zippel_lemma), and thus they all take place in a polynomial setting.

There are constructions that do not take place in a polynomial setting, such as the [expander-graph based PCP](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~dinuri/mypapers/combpcp.pdf). But they are impractical both asymptotically and in practice.

Are there constructions that do not take place in a polynomial setting, but are still potentially practical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look the Groth-Sahai proof system; Its practical and has been well studied and it's not reliable to The Schwarz-Zippel lemma.
But it depends of the form of the equations you want to prove.